# Spring Security: Logout Isn't working - "requested resource not available"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

So, I'm trying to get my first ever practice application with Spring Security working. It's just a simple test to try and see if I can just get the basics working, before moving on to more complex implementations.

I'm using Spring Security 4 btw, with Spring 4.2.2.

Right now, I have a welcome page and an admin page. Trying to access the admin page is intercepted and redirected to the default Spring Security login form. From there, I can login and be authenticated to access the admin page.

On the admin page, I have a logout link. This is where it goes wrong. I have two logout links right now, for two different methods I've tried of making this work.

The first is a simple URL. It uses the  tag, and within it is the JSTL  tag. I'm trying to call the logout URL there. When I do, I get an HTTP Status 404 page with a description saying The requested resource is not available.

The second way is with a form. I try having a submit button in a form, with the form's action attribute set to the logout URL and the method set to post.

This one gives me a more complex error, which I'll copy and paste here:

Title: HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Type: Status report

Message:  Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Description: Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

The url of the error page in both cases, btw, is localhost:8080/spring-security/logout. spring-security being the name of this test app.

So, I'm a bit lost. This is my first time working with Spring Security, and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Below I'm pasting my admin.jsp page and my spring-security.xml page.

Thanks in advance.

admin.jsp page:

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%@ include file="jstl-stub.jsp" %> <!-- Include links to JSTL Libraries -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Title: ${title}</h1>

<h1>Message: ${message}</h1>

<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
    <h2>Welcome: ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
    | <a href="<c:url value="/logout"/>">Logout</a></h2>

    <br><br>

    <form action="logout" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="logout"/>
    </form>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/welcome"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider >
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the second problem is with your post method. I saw that you are using security 4.0, and 4.0 is enabled csrf protection by default. If you do not want to have this, you have to disable it.

> As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with
>   XML configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF protection, the
>   corresponding XML configuration can be seen below.
>
> ```
> <http>
>   <!-- ... -->
>   <csrf disabled="true"/>
> </http>
> ```

See below link
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure

But if you want to add csrf protection, you need to add header to the post method.

This tutorial may help you.

http://myshittycode.com/2015/03/30/spring-security-invalid-csrf-token-null-was-found-on-the-request-parameter-_csrf-or-header-x-csrf-token/

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    // other code ...
}
```

disable the csrf will work for you. and allow you to call `/logout` by get method .